# Inconsistent solution to nonlinear first order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to solve the following first order differential equation,
$$
y'(x)=-\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{y(x)}   
$$
with boundary condition of,
$$
y(c)=d
$$
The above equation is the Abel's equation which has a complicated and lengthy method of solving it.   I am looking for something that is simple to begin with.
I am not sure if my approach is correct, but my attempted solution is by differentiating it and solving,
$$
y''=\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{by'}{y^2}
$$
The above equation is still nonlinear but it has an obvious solution which is $$y=Ax $$ where A is an arbitrary constant.  Plugging into second order differential equation yields,
$$
 0= \frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{Ab}{A^2x^2}
$$
and solving for A gives $$A= \frac{-b}{a} $$
However, if I use the solution to first order equation I will get inconsistent results or
$$
-b/a=0
$$
Does that mean that differentiating approach is incorrect way to start solving or I missed some steps in solving it?  Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Consider the equation $y=0$. Differentiating yields $y'=0$ which has a solution $y=c$ for any constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$. But $y=c$ doesn't satisfy the original equation for all constants $c$... Moral of the story: differentiating introduces erroneous solutions.

Comment: If you let $y(x)=Ax,$ then $$-\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{y(x)}=\frac{a}{x}-\frac{\frac{b}{A}}{x}=-\frac{(a+\frac{b}{A})}{x},$$ but $y'(x)=A.$ So you have the false equality $A=-\frac{(a+\frac{b}{A})}{x},$ which means the solution you gave definitely does not solve the equation. The problem lies with the differentiation. A function can be a solution to $y''=df(x, y)/dy\cdot{y'}$ without actually being a solution to $y'=f(x,y).$  It is just as epiliam said.